# Create subform and append it in exisiting form in symfony 3

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have this configuration :

```
ModuleModelType
| - title
| - created
| - subform
| - DevField1 
| - DevField2 
| - etc...
```

What I want to have is something like this :

```
ModuleModelType
| - title
| - created
| - subform
|   | - DevField1 
|   | - DevField2 
|   | - etc...
```

But the problem is that i don't know what users will add to the form, as I'm creating a reusable bundle and I don't want name conflicts.

This is my code, how I can make this easily ? 
I want a developer can create a class and append his own form in an existing form.The following existing code append the dev's form into the first one and can replace some existing keys if keys are the same. 
Actually, I want to append all dev's fields into and `subform` to avoid this.

```
<?php
// Into a controller
/** @var ModuleInterface $instance */
$instance = ... ;
$form = $this->createForm(ModuleModelType::class);
$subform= $this->createForm(new FormType());
$instance->buildForm($subform);
$form->add('subform',$subform); // I want to make something like that

interface ModuleInterface
{
    public function buildForm(Form &$form);
}

class Foo implements ModuleInterface
{
    public function buildForm(Form &$builder)
    {
        $builder->add("DevField1", /* type */);
        $builder->add("DevField2", /* type */);
    }
}

class ModuleModelType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('created')
            ->add('subform')
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain more detail? what you want to solve?

Comment: How can i build à second form generated by à développer and append it to thé first form

Comment: Développer has to create his own class that must implement ModuleInterface and add his own fields on buildform function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will assume some facts :

- You want to have an entity with "data" field
- This "data" field must be an array
- A form must be changed to handle this "data" field
- Obviously, in the entity, we can load and save "data" informations, as an array

This behavior can be easily done passing the subform by constructor.
Your problem happen because you're fighting against Symfony, please considere a standard way :

- Have an entity with "array" field type
- Have two forms Type : First one to handle your entity, second one to handle the embedded form.
- Use dependency injection to embed the right form. (Assume two services by Module : first one for the embedded form, second one for you.

**Your entity** : (Think to generate getters & setters with generate:doctrine:entities)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Foo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FooRepository")
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="some_informations", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $someInformations;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Data", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $data;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="data", type="array")
     */
    private $data;
```

**Your form** :

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FooType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $dataFormName;
    public function __construct($dataFormName)
    {
        $this->dataFormName = $dataFormName;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('someInformations')
            ->add('data', $this->dataFormName)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Foo'
        ));
    }
}
```

**Your subform** :

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SubformType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('content')
            ->add('some_data')
        ;
    }
}
```

At this point, you should be able to generate your form with :

```
$foo = new Foo();
$form = $this->createForm('service_name_for_the_form_with_second_embedded', $foo);
```

**Old answer** :

In this case, you should assume that ModuleInterface extends FormTypeInterface.
To be used as FormType in a $form->add, your class should look like a form.
At this point, use ModuleInterface seems to be useless.
I can purpose that way for you :

```php
<?php
// Into a controller
$instance = new Foo();
$form = $this->createForm(new ModuleModelType($instance));

class Foo extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add("DevField1");
        $builder->add("DevField2");
    }
}

class ModuleModelType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $subform;
    function __construct(FormTypeInterface $subform)
    {
        $this->subform = $subform;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('created')
            ->add('subform', $this->subform)
        ;
    }
}
```

You can also use dependency injection to inject $instance through __construct.
Take care about naming convention for "Foo" class, should be FooType ;)

If you do something like that, your expected form will be OK.

Have a nice day,

Gaël

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already read this careful: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

In your case, you can do by:

```
use path/of/your/formType/to/embed;
class ModuleModelType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('created')
            ->add('subform', Foo::class)
        ;
    }
}
```

Don't worry about interface. Interface just must to implement, I hope you already know that.

I dont know why you want add in controller, because you have already form class, you just need modify to make clean your code.

I you want subform as add by user, you can do by collection form embed: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Or you want by data (show form if submitted) : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

**NOTE:** Symfony ver 3.0 are different with 2.~.

Comment: I actually read the docs fully, Your solution as Nainterceptor's one is to use abstarct types to add form fields, which this is not what I want, I want an user can create his own modules by creating a class that implements ModuleInterface which contains buildForm, getData and many other things who doesn't relate to abstractYpes and forms. 

I already know that solution, (it is in the doc actually =) ) but i'm looking for one who doesn't use abstractTypes